# Get the name of a python variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def f(s)
  print <name of s> = s
```

I wish to output "hello=10" for `f(hello)`, given that the variable hello has value 10.

The problem is how to get the variable name of the variable, i.e., `<name of s>`?

This is for debugging purpose.
Say given a new statement `s=2`

`f(s)` before the new statement will print `s=0` if `s` is initially 0, `f(s)` after the new statement will print `s=2`.

I can easily write:

```
def f(name,value)
   print "%s=%s"%(name,str(value))
```

and use it as `f("s",s)`, but that would need me to input two arguments, which is more cumbersome.

Comment: How can you print it without knowing a name?

Comment: When you pass an argument to a function, a *value* is passed.  The function has no way of knowing what name is associated with that value.

Comment: @iCodez i see, that is too bad...

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: For debugging purpose, I can write a function say before(s), after(s), and put it before and after a new statement, this can save some typing.

Comment: The best solution to your problem might be using a debugger program to run your script.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if it is actually worth it, but using the information from frames for simple function calls with positional arguments you can do something like this:

```
import inspect

def hello(s1, s2, s3, s4):
    args = inspect.getargspec(hello).args
    line = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1][4][0]
    actual_args = map(str.strip, line[line.index('(')+1: line.index(')')].split(','))
    for x, y in zip(args, actual_args):
        print "value of {} is {}".format(y, locals()[x])

a, b, c, d = 1, 2, 3, 4
hello(a, b, c, d)
```

#### output:

```
value of a is 1
value of b is 2
value of c is 3
value of d is 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You could (probably) do this using the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module.

```
import traceback
def some_func(x):
    stack = traceback.extract_stack()
    calling = stack[-2]
    func_call_str = calling[-1]
    print func_call_str
```

There are probably lots of caveats that I'm unaware of, but at least calling `some_func(hello)` should print `some_func(hello)` and you can just proceed and extract the "variable name" using string extraction methods.

Answer (score -1):

If you have only one argument there for the function; then you can do this way.

```
def f(s):
    var, val = locals.items()[0]  # `var` will always have value 's', so no much difference here.
    print "{} = {}".format(var, val)
```

In your case the passing argument ( Actual parameter ) name won't be available once it passed in to the function ( Formal parameter ).

Answer (score -2):

You can do it this way:

```
def func(**kwargs):
    for key in kwargs:
        print 'Var <%s> with value <%s>' % (key, kwargs[key])

>>> func(say=2, qqq=3)
    Var <say> with value <2>
    Var <qqq> with value <3>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question: `say` and `qqq` are keys, not variable names.