# How to get name of function's actual parameters in Python?

Tags: python, introspection, python-internals

For example:

```
def func(a):
    # how to get the name "x"

x = 1
func(x)
```

If I use `inspect` module I can get the stack frame object:

```
import inspect
def func(a):
    print inspect.stack()
```

out:

```
[
(<frame object at 0x7fb973c7a988>, 'ts.py', 9, 'func', ['  stack = inspect.stack()\n'], 0)

(<frame object at 0x7fb973d74c20>, 'ts.py', 18, '<module>', ['func(x)\n'], 0)
]
```

or use `inspect.currentframe()` I can get the current frame.

But I can only get the name `"a"` by inspect the function object.

Use `inspect.stack` I can get the call stack:`"['func(x)\n']"`,

How can I get the name of actual parameters(`"x"` here) when call the `func` by parsing the `"['func(x)\n']"`?

If I call `func(x)` then I get `"x"`

if I call `func(y)` then I get `"y"`

### Edit:

A example:

```
def func(a):

    # Add 1 to acttual parameter
    ...

x = 1
func(x)
print x # x expected to 2

y = 2
func(y)
print y # y expected to 3
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: What would you expect to get in the case `l = [1]; func(l[0])`? The case `a = b = 1; func(b)`? This seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I agree with @DanielRoseman, if you tell us why you want to do this, maybe we can suggest an alternative approach

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because I want to impelment Reference Parameters like in C++.

Comment: lists are already references, if you want to assign a value that affects the outern scope use the keyword `global`

Comment: @markcial What I do now is a monkey patch actually..

Comment: use a decorator that makes that variable global

Comment: Or better yet, return a value from the function

Comment: @markcial But not only one variable.

Comment: can you please give a more concrete sample showing what you want to achieve, the sample you provided is way to generic

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/3001761?

Comment: Related: [Get the name of a python variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590570/get-the-name-of-a-python-variable)

Comment: @atupal just don't do that. Either have mutable arguments and return `None` (c.f. `random.shuffle`) or `return` new objects for immutable arguments and assign them explicitly: `x = func(x)`. Breaking Python to ape another language will only lead to confusion and difficult-to-maintain code.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your comment explanations, the reason you are trying to do this is:

> Because I want to impelment Reference Parameters like in C++

You can't do that. In python, everything is passed by value, but that value is a reference to the object you pass. Now, if that object is mutable (like a list), you can modify it, but if it's immutable, a new object is created and set. In your code example, `x` is an `int` which is immutable, so if you want to change the value of `x` it, just return its new value from the function you are invoking:

```
def func(a):
    b = 5 * a
    # ... some math
    return b


x = 1
x = func(x)
```

So what if you want to return multiple values? Use a `tuple`!

```
def func(a, b):
    a, b = 5 * b, 6 * a
    # ...
    return b, a

a, b = 2, 3
a, b = func(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

That is feasible, up to a point - but nonetheless,useless in any kind of "real code".
You can use it for backyard magic tricks:

Just retrieve the calling stack_frame like you are doing,
then loop linearly through the variables  available in the calling frame for
one that references the same object you got as a parameter. The variables are in the
`f_locals` and `f_globals` dictionaries which are attributes of the frame object.

Of course, the parameter passed may not be in a variable name to start with: 
it might be a constant in the caller, or it might be inside a dict or a list.

Either way, as @Nasser put it in the answer: it is not the way Python works. Objects exist in memory, and variable names, in each scope, just point to those objects. The names themselves are meaningless otherwise.

```
import inspect
from itertools import chain

def magic(x):
    # note that in Python2, 'currentframe' could get a parameter
    # to indicate which frame you want on the stack. Not so in Python3
    fr = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    for var_name, value in chain(fr.f_locals.items(),  fr.f_globals.items()):
        if value is x:
            print ("The variable name in the caller context is {}".format(var_name))


def caler():
   y = "My constant"
   magic(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

use lists as  references

```
def func(a):
   a[0] = a[0] + 1

x = [1]
func(x)
print x[0] # x expected to 2

y = [2]
func(y)
print y[0] # y expected to 3
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my final solution. Use [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) to parse the function statement and get the args.:

```
import inspect
import re
import ast

def func(a,b,c):
  stack = inspect.stack()
  stack_pre = stack[1]
  function_call_string = ';'.join( stack_pre[4] ).strip('\n')
  ret = re.search(r'(%s[ ]*\(.*\))' % func.func_name, function_call_string)
  striped_function_call_string = ret.group()
  parser = ast.parse(striped_function_call_string)

  frame = inspect.currentframe()
  for arg in parser.body[0].value.args:
    iter_frame = frame.f_back
    while iter_frame:
      if arg.id in iter_frame.f_locals:
        iter_frame.f_locals[arg.id] += 1
        break
      iter_frame = iter_frame.f_back

x=1;y=2;z=3;func(x,y,z)
print x,y,z
```

Out:

`2 3 4`