# find names of Python function arguments _in caller_

Tags: python, arguments

Suppose that I call a function `f` with a statement like the following:

```
f(a, b, x)
```

Inside the function `f`, I would like to be able to determine the names of the variables that the caller passed.  (I realize that this is bad programming practice).  Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Related: [Get the name of a python variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26590570/846892)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find your variables in `vars()` `locals()` and `globals()`. 
You should search for the id of your variable in those dictionaries but there are some problems when you are in a sub-function. Then you could still give environment parameters like [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) does for example.